# Xamarin Android change global button style

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-styles

I have an app from a college where I need to change the color of all Buttons when they are focused (on the vuzix m300 smartglass (4.2)). Focused and unfocused buttons are barely distinguishable.

So how can I just change the color of a focused Button, while leaving everything else intact?

Basically, I want to override the global settings of Buttons without having to go into each layout and having to add styles.

Edit:
A have a selector defined in my `button_style.xml` inside my drawable folder but in order to apply it I would have to change each axml file manually.

drawable\button_style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_focused="true" >
    <shape>
      <solid
          android:color="#77faff" />
      <stroke
          android:width="1dp"
          android:color="#444444" />
      <corners
          android:radius="6dp" />
      <padding
          android:left="10dp"
          android:top="10dp"
          android:right="10dp"
          android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

values\styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="button_style" parent="android:style/Widget.Button"></style>
</resources>
```

But this would only apply to a button once I add
"style="@style/button_style" to it. I want to auto apply it to every Button in my app.

Comment: Use **Selector** for button style.

Comment: and how to I apply the selector to the default style

Comment: You have to create your own style for the button.
Check this: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/style_a_button/

Comment: yes this shows me how to change one button not every button

Comment: But you can apply this style to all button. the thing is you need to create your own style of buttons.

Comment: I have my own style for buttons I want to override the default style so I don't have to use style="@style/button_text" on every instance where I use button in the app

Comment: Can you please post your code? what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <resources>
   <style name="button_style" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
     <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_style</item>
   </style>
 </resources>
```